# TypeError: <open file 'data', mode 'r' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-storm

I got error in opening a file which contains text like

```
rt @whufc_news : west ham are the only team in the top half of the premier league without a player in the england squad . !url
rt @blackpplvines : don't say anything just rt_ !url
```

the code is

```
class SimSpout(storm.Spout):
def initialize(self, conf, context):
   self.f = 'data'
   self._conf = conf
   self._context = context
   self._offset = 0
   storm.logInfo("Spout instance starting...")
def nextTuple(self):
  with open(self.f) as l:
    l.readlines()[self._offset]
    storm.logInfo("Emiting %s" % l)
    storm.emit([l])
    self._offset = self._offset + 1
SimSpout().run()
```

the error is

```
TypeError: <open file 'data', mode 'r' at 0x7f04e1b7f1e0> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: The error message is bigger than that... it shows the line that raised the error. You took that out because you want to make us work for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells it all. You tried to serialize a file object, not data read from the file. You need to put the data you read into a variable and send that.

```
class SimSpout(storm.Spout):
  def initialize(self, conf, context):
     self.f = 'data'
     self._conf = conf
     self._context = context
     self._offset = 0
     storm.logInfo("Spout instance starting...")
  def nextTuple(self):
    with open(self.f) as l:
      data = l.readlines()[self._offset]
      storm.logInfo("Emiting %s" % data)
      storm.emit([data])
      self._offset = self._offset + 1
SimSpout().run()
```